# Zustand is not updating nested object based state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, zustand

I'm experimenting a problem with Zustand, I'm updating a state that is based on another state that is in a nested object, this state is not being updated properly... here an example:

```js
mapUpdate: (update: Partial<MapState['map']>) => {
  set((state) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      map: {
        ...state.map,
        ...update,
        canShowCarouselResults:
          state.map.zoom >= MIN_MAP_RESULTS_CAROUSEL_ZOOM,
      },
      canShowMarketResults: state.map.zoom <= MIN_RESULTS_ZOOM,
    };
  });
}
```

I need to update `canShowMArketResults` according to zoom state, zoom state is in map state object... the zoom state is updating correctly but the `canShowMarketResoults` status is not taking some map.zoom changes.